# Jquery-ui tabs (ajax).... stop tab reloading url when tab is re-selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery ui tabs and im adding tabs dynamically using .tabs('add'...). The tabs load a url using ajax. The problem is that everytime i click on another tab then come back... the tab reloads the url. i want the url loaded once.... any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`cache`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-cache) option (this defaults to `false`):

> Whether or not to cache remote tabs
>   content, e.g. load only once or with
>   every click.

For example:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ cache:true });
```

Here's a simple demo. Use Firebug or another tool to make sure that the content isn't being retrieved more than once per tab: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/D6qkW/

Comment: thanx andrew, life saver... my deadline was 2morro and this had stalled me. thanx again

Comment: anyway if you don't accept my edit))   The cache option is deprecated: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event

Comment: @lvil: I didn't get a chance to review the edit (it's already been rejected), but thanks for the heads up--I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: Now removed in favour of self-coding the functionality in the beforeLoad event http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event

Answer (score 25):

Please note that the `cache` property of the tabs options was deprecated in jQueryUI 1.9 and removed in 1.10. See the [jQueryUI 1.9 upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event)

The recommended way to handle this now, is to use the new `beforeLoad` event to prevent the XHR request from running.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
    if ( ui.tab.data( "loaded" ) ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    ui.jqXHR.success(function() {
      ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that ui.jqXHR.success is deprecated and removed as of jQuery 3.0. Solution above must be modified to use the tab load event to set ui-tab.data('loaded',true)

Comment: modified solution posted below

Answer (score 3):

Turn on caching on the tabs, or alternatively enable the globabl ajax cache option in jQuery, when something changes that requires a reload, dynamically append something like Math.Rand() to the end of the URL so that it won't cache the next load.

From the jQuery site for tab caching:

```
Code examples Initialize a tabs with the cache option specified. $( ".selector" ).tabs({ cache: true }); Get or set the cache option, after init. //getter
var cache = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "cache" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "cache", true );
```

Comment: caching my tabs works great... u musta misunderstood the question but the code has helped..voted up

Comment: I meant turn "on" caching --- hence the code; glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to store a boolean value. Initially set at false(ajax not loaded). When your ajax loads set the boolean to true and check the value before each ajax request.

Of course you would need to do a little more work to handle more than one tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.tab.data("loaded")) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                ui.ajaxSettings.cache = false,
                ui.panel.html('<img src="images/prettyPhoto/dark_square/loader.gif" width="24" height="24" style="vertical-align:middle;"> Loading...'),
                ui.jqXHR.success(function() {
                    ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );
                }),
                ui.jqXHR.error(function () {
                    ui.panel.html(
                    "Couldn't load Data. Plz Reload Page or Try Again Later.");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 3.0 jqXHR.success was removed, solution (modified form CheekySoft above) is now

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  beforeLoad: function(event,ui){
    if(ui.tab.data("loaded")){
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
  },
  load: function(event,ui){
    ui.tab.data("loaded",true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your AJAX calls within an `if` statement which checks for a previous AJAX call, i.e.:

```
var ajaxed = false

if ( ajaxed == false ) {
    // your ajax call
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "test.js",
       dataType: "html"
       success: function(data){
          // insert html into DOM
          ajaxed = true
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the same problem here is the perfect answer and please prefer the link below:

```
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
    if ( ui.tab.data( "loaded" ) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    ui.jqXHR.success(function() {
        ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );
    });
}
```

});

[Deprecated ajaxOptions and cache options added beforeLoad event](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event)